# Should I use public IP or private IP for connecting servers within the same VPC?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, mysql-replication

I have 2 Linux servers on AWS. Both servers are in the default vpc (aws default vpc). Both of these servers have their own Elastic IP. I also have a webServer which is inside the same vpc.

I want to run a replicated MySQL on these 2 servers, so one server would be master and the other slave.

I need to provide an ip address for each MySQL server, so in my.cnf, there is a setting: `bind-address`

Should I use the public or private IP for the bind-address? (All the computers who need access to MySQL server are in the same vpc).

Note both servers are in the same Security Group and I have opened all the ports within the security group.

Comment: You'd want to use the internal IPs for this.

Comment: What made you think the external addresses would possibly be preferable?

Comment: I am just a programmer... it's the first time that I working with Networks/Subnets/VPC etc... I thought it has to be the private ip, but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use internal IP addresses for your instances to talk to each other. If you use their public or elastic IP addresses, you are [charged](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) for in-region network data transfer. There is no charge for using the private IP addresses.

Comment: This is correct, except that there is a charge for private IPv4 address traffic from one availability zone to another within the same VPC (and within the same AZ for traffic crossing a VPC peering connection).

Comment: True, but the charge is less than the charge for using the elastic IP.